# Remove script using document.removeChild() in chrome

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a html page that has many html/head/script tags which loads scripts from remote locations. I want to remove the scripts from the page programmatically after the page is loaded.

To remove the script, I'm using the `removeChild` method of the `DOMElement`.

```
element.removeChild(child);
```

This call executes successfully, but the functions loaded from the script are still in memory. There is no effect on the loaded functions.

I have also tried:

```
element.replaceChild( new, old );
```

Both have no effect.
Is this a bug or feature?
How to remove a previously loaded script programmatically?

Comment: Are you not able to simply leave out the `.js` files causing the problems?

Comment: If only it were that easy... `:P`...

Answer (score 3):

Removing a script element after it has been loaded does not remove the scripts themselves.  There is no way I know of to "unload" scripts that have already been loaded.  If there are targeted functions that you want to replace, you can redefine those global symbols which will just replace the old code with different code, but javascript doesn't provide the ability to unload.

For example, if the script has a global function called `callMe()`, you can just redefine that function in the global scope to something else:

```
function callMe() { /* replacement function that does nothing */}
```

Whichever definition comes last will be in force.

Comment: interesting. How do I redefine the global functions? forgive me, I'm new to javaScript development.

Comment: @Nambi - I added a little more to my answer about replacing a function.

Comment: If "function callMe()" is inside another remote script and the remote script is added to dom using appendChild(), will it redefine "callMe()" ?

Comment: @Nambi - if `callMe()` is a globally accessible function in any script and you run the redefinition code after the dynamically loaded script has been loaded, yes it will redefine it.